# "Invalid window handle" win32 exception

Tags: c#, .net, windows

Does anyone know what could cause the exception below in a C# application?

I am reproducing it consistently on my machine by doing this:

1. I open a particular dialog (WPF window)
2. I make some selection and close the window
3. several seconds after closing it, I get the exception with the stack trace below

It seems to happen on my machine only, I could not reproduce it on other machines.

EDIT: 
The ClientToScreen method does not seem to be called directly from user code - I could not find other relevant threads so I assume the crash is a side effect of some previous operation.

EDIT2:
By doing a binary search in the code (commenting it), I could see that this seems to be caused by the Cleanup method below being called in the OnClosing handler of the view model - that method is calling among other things a Dispose on an object which acts like a WPF wrapper for a Windows forms. Once I commented it, the crash does not happen anymore.

```
protected override void OnClosing(System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
   base.OnClosing(e);
   m_pickerViewModel.Cleanup();
}

public bool CloseView() 
{
    this.Dispose(true);
    return true; 
}
```

Exception stack trace

```
System.Transactions Critical: 0 : <TraceRecord xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/10/E2ETraceEvent/TraceRecord" Severity="Critical"><TraceIdentifier>http://msdn.microsoft.com/TraceCodes/System/ActivityTracing/2004/07/Reliability/Exception/Unhandled</TraceIdentifier><Description>Unhandled exception</Description><AppDomain>App.exe</AppDomain><Exception><ExceptionType>System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</ExceptionType><Message>Invalid window handle</Message><StackTrace>   at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.ClientToScreen(HandleRef hWnd, POINT pt)
   at MS.Internal.PointUtil.ClientToScreen(Point pointClient, PresentationSource presentationSource)
   at System.Windows.Input.MouseDevice.GlobalHitTest(Boolean clientUnits, Point pt, PresentationSource inputSource, IInputElement&amp;amp; enabledHit, IInputElement&amp;amp; originalHit)
   at System.Windows.Input.MouseDevice.PreNotifyInput(Object sender, NotifyInputEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessStagingArea()
   at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessInput(InputEventArgs input)
   at System.Windows.Input.MouseDevice.Synchronize()
   at System.Windows.Input.MouseDevice.OnHitTestInvalidatedAsync(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.HitTestInvalidatedAsyncCallback(Object arg)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeInSecurityContext(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean&amp;amp; handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean&amp;amp; handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
   at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG&amp;amp; msg)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame frame)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(DispatcherFrame frame)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run()
   at System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(Object ignore)
   at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(Window window)
   at System.Windows.Application.Run(Window window)
   at System.Windows.Application.Run()
   at App.AppAppExe.Main(String[] args)</StackTrace><ExceptionString>System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): Invalid window handle
   at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.ClientToScreen(HandleRef hWnd, POINT pt)
   at MS.Internal.PointUtil.ClientToScreen(Point pointClient, PresentationSource presentationSource)
   at System.Windows.Input.MouseDevice.GlobalHitTest(Boolean clientUnits, Point pt, PresentationSource inputSource, IInputElement&amp;amp; enabledHit, IInputElement&amp;amp; originalHit)
   at System.Windows.Input.MouseDevice.PreNotifyInput(Object sender, NotifyInputEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessStagingArea()
   at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessInput(InputEventArgs input)
   at System.Windows.Input.MouseDevice.Synchronize()
   at System.Windows.Input.MouseDevice.OnHitTestInvalidatedAsync(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.HitTestInvalidatedAsyncCallback(Object arg)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeInSecurityContext(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean&amp;amp; handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean&amp;amp; handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
   at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG&amp;amp; msg)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame frame)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(DispatcherFrame frame)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run()
   at System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(Object ignore)
   at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(Window window)
   at System.Windows.Application.Run(Window window)
   at System.Windows.Application.Run()
   at App.AppAppExe.Main(String[] args)</ExceptionString><NativeErrorCode>578</NativeErrorCode><DataItems><Data></Data></DataItems></Exception></TraceRecord>
The thread '<Thread Ended>' (0x38bc) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

Comment: Gotta love those WPF stack traces.  The window closed but didn't say goodbye nicely.  Post repro code instead.

Comment: Without seeing any code, what it looks like there is a background task that is calling `ClientToScreen` function. This function is trying to get to convert the coordinates of the mouse location in the window you closed to screen coordinates. Since the window is closed though, it is failing.

Comment: There's a very strange Windows error code visible in the trace.  Are you running this machine without a paging file?  Don't do that.

Comment: I checked for the paging file, it is enabled so it seems it's not caused by that. Couldn't find yet any call to ClientToScreen in the solution, I will search more in the libraries being called.

Comment: Do you want help from us or not? If you do, post SSCCE.

Comment: I've edited the question to include my findings, see EDIT2.

Comment: I have also seen this exception when dragging a WPF window that hosts a non-WPF element via its HWND. You mention that in your question too.